# Why doesn't FlatList scroll smoothly till the end of the list on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image: FlatList abruptly stops and renders again]

As you can view it in the GIF, on scrolling the list swiftly, the scrolling stops at the end and on scrolling again, the next set of data loads. This continues until the list ends. This is only happening on Android. I can smoothly scroll through the list till the end on iOS without any abrupt scroll stops.

But on Android, there is an abrupt scroll stop and then on scrolling again, the next set of the list is loaded. Please note that I have also tested it on the actual device and the issue persists.

The user might feel that he/she has reached the end of the list and might not scroll further.

Below is the code that has been written to render FlatList:

```
<FlatList
  data={ showtimeList }
  renderItem={ this.renderShowtimesSection }
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={ false }
  keyExtractor={ this.getListKey }
  extraData={ this.props }
  initialNumToRender={ 10 }
/>
```

`showtimeList` holds a static array of objects. I am not making any API calls to load additional data on reaching the end.

Is there anything I can do to optimize the code for smooth scrolling without any scroll stops? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: How are you loading more data? Your code sample doesn't include onEndReached or onScroll events, so how do you know when to fetch the next data set? Or is this happening just with a single, static `showtimeList` data set?

Comment: @jevakallio My bad. I'll add this detail to the question. The data is static.

Comment: That behaviour you are seeing should not be happening - doesn't happen for me. Can you try to replicate it on this Snack? https://snack.expo.io/HkEiz6P5b

Comment: @rash.tay are you able to solve this?

Comment: @jevakallio Sorry for the late response. I tried to resolve it with some tweaks. I'll try reproducing it on Snack.

Comment: @ManjeetSingh Yeah. I add extra padding at the bottom so that the users can scroll more and by then the next data get's loaded. You need to perform certain tweaks as well. For example, 
1. try to pass only relevant data to the FlatList, 
2. verify if multiple re-renders are happening and try to reduce it,
3. make sure you perform fewer operations on the data when you are looping through it via the FlatList (this is not possible in every scenario). Maybe you can perform all operations on the data before you pass it to FlatList.

Comment: well in my case I end up wrapping Flatlist within Scrollview